# Value range of normal distribution function

Tags: brdf

Is the normal distribution term D in the Cook-Torrance BRDF supposed to be between 0 and 1? What does this number actually represent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term D is a [probability density function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) (PDF) of microfacets' directions. Vaguely speaking, it says what "portion" of all microfacets points in the given direction.

Since it is a PDF, it doesn't have to be less or equal to 1. It can, and often is, higher than 1 for some directions.